# Clustering Event log

Tags: python, process, cluster-analysis, event-log, variant

What should be the value for eventlog clustering (Process Mining) using pm4py the Python library?

```py
clusterer.algorithm.apply(log, trace_attribute=None, variant=VARIANT_DMM_LEVEN, parameters=None)
```